# Entry way doors from garage and driveway

Tags: doors

I have a patio that was converted into a family room by the previous owners. The only exterior door entry to this room is from the driveway. The only entrance to the garage is through the garage door from the driveway. If the powered garage door were ever to break down, we would have no way of getting into the garage.

I am going to remodel the family room ( *marked as "TV Room" in the picture* ). The best place for a door from the family room into the garage for my planned layout of the room is what I show in the picture. Obviously it's also the worst place since the door to the garage can bang into the door to the driveway.

But I'm willing to live with that unless someone knows of a serious reason why I can't or shouldn't do that, such as a probable code violation. I'm in Missouri, USA.

[image]

Comment: Why do you need two doors that are 3 feet apart?

Comment: Move the Garage/TV door closer to where it says "TV" or change that hinging door so that it swings _into_ the garage instead of into the TV Room. I'd opt for the 2nd option. Generally, for fire safety you want emergency egress doors to open out. Escaping the "house" into the "garage" in event of a fire, it would be easier to push the door out than pull it towards you, especially if panicked family members are crowding behind you.

Comment: Doors leading to garages from living areas must be fire-rated and self-closing. I agree that the door to the garage should swing into the garage.

Comment: But I thought garage doors should swing in for security purposes. Garages are easy to break into. Once inside, if the door swings out, the hinges are accessible. As I said, I need a door into the garage should the roll up door fail closed. I also would not run into the garage when an outside door is right next to it. I know the type of door to buy. @JimmyFix-it

Comment: I don't that it's a code requirement that outside entry doors swing out.  All of mine swing into the house.  If the door swing out, then the hinges would have to be on the outside of the house (I think), compromising the security of the door.

Comment: I recommended it swing out (open into the garage) because of the interference issue depicted in the illustration, security was not mentioned as a concern. There are ways to alleviate the hinge pin issue: hinges with pin set-screw only accessible when the door is open.

Comment: Another concern arises if the garage floor is lower then than of the TV room.   If you have a step (or two) up from the garage to the TV room, then the door cannot swing out into the garage unless there is a landing of the proper size in the garage.

Comment: @FreeMan I've never lived in (or can recall seeing) a house with a garage door (or any other exterior door) that opened to the outside...